# Conda environments in VS Code showing up twice but working as expected

Tags: visual-studio-code, conda

When starting up VS Code, my terminal often shows this bug where my active environment and the base environment both seem to be activated.

When I check the version of python, it is the version from the 'test' environment so I know it's activated correctly, I think.

When I deactivate, as expected, it goes from my active ('test') environment to my base environment. Then when I deactivate again, it goes out of conda. Then when I reactivate, it starts correctly.

Is this a known issue or likely to cause issues when running code? How do I fix it?

```
>>> (test) (base) admin@ADMINs-MacBook-Pro new_folder % conda info --envs

# conda environments:
#
base                     /Users/admin/miniconda3
test                  *  /Users/admin/miniconda3/envs/test

>>> (test) (base) admin@ADMINs-MacBook-Pro new_folder % conda deactivate

>>> (base) (base) admin@ADMINs-MacBook-Pro new_folder % conda deactivate

>>> admin@ADMINs-MacBook-Pro new_folder % conda activate test

>>> (test) admin@ADMINs-MacBook-Pro new_folder %
```